# Python idle doesn't let install telepot in shell using calling through subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess, telegram-bot

I have been trying to install 'telepot' by using subprocess calling in python idle shell 3.6 since I have python version 2.7 already installed as main system version.

I used this code installing

```
from subprocess import call
call(['install', 'telepot'])
1
import telepot
```

I was successful in importing the library one time but then next time it again showed

ModuleNotFoundError:no module named 'telepot'

I have also tried

```
call(['pip', 'install', 'telepot'])
```

But it failed.
So what should I do to install it in python shell without using command line or terminal

Comment: Why can't you use command line?

Comment: Because I have multiple versions of python installed and the modules I install goes directly to python 2.7,but I want to use the module in python 3.6

Comment: So you should go to the needed directory and then install there)

Answer (score 0):

So firstly you need to open command line (press Win + R and write there 'cmd.exe', press ok)
Then write there `cd C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages`
And then write `pip install telepot`
Done)